# Laravel - push array to collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, push

I have this code where I try to grab all auth user categories:

```
$cats = Auth::user()->cats()->lists('title','id');
```

and I want to add new data to $cats so I write:

```
 $cats->push(['5','BMW']);
```

but I got:

```
    Collection {#459 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    9 => "asd"
    10 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "5"
      1 => "BMW"
    ]
  ]
}
```

How I to change my code to get this result:

```
Collection {#459 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    9 => "asd"
    5 => "BMW"
  ]
}
```

So how I can add the array to this collection? 
p.s. I need this format because I use select2 jquery plugin

Comment: Is the new data really `['5','BMW']`? Or `['5' => 'BMW']`?

Comment: ['5' => 'BMW']...

Comment: Use `->put(5, ‘BMW’)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the collection like an array:

```
$cats[5] = 'BMW';
```